# NVDA is not reading image alt text in Chrome

Tags: html, nvda

NVDA isn't reading the image's alt text in Chrome, not even with keyboard or mouse hover. It is reading it perfectly in Firefox and Edge.

```html
<div class="card card_home_category" data-category="Computers">
  <div class="med_image">
    <img src="image.png" alt="alt text" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="h5 my-2 stretched-link" title="title">
    Computers
  </a>
</div>
```

I've also tried it with `aria-label` but nothing seems to work with Chrome.

Comment: Works great for me with NVDA in Chrome. How are you navigating? I used the down arrow to navigate to each element. I heard "graphic alt text".

Comment: I try navigating with down arrow as well as tab and mouse hover too. But nothing working. Is there any NVDA setting may be I am missing?

Comment: Tab won’t work because your image is not a keyboard focusable element. The down arrow in NVDA walks the DOM. You don’t have to set anything to use it.

Comment: Okay. what about mouse hover, it is working on other browser.

Comment: Mouse hover with a screen reader is typically not a testing scenario because it’s not a situation that happens very often by real users.